# Debug what #DEFINE resolves to before compilation

Tags: c, debugging, cmake, makefile, precompiler

I need to see what is happeing under the hood before compilation. How? The following is an example out of many...

I am compiling the [Intel Math Lib](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library.html) and that works fine. There are different options to get it running that influence how symbols are defined during precompilation.

I can deduct from the "build code" (make/cmake), what should happen, but my expectations don't match the results. Therefore I would now like to "look into it" and see what actually happens.

Example (simplyfied from `bid_conf.h` in the mentioned Intel library): The client code using the math library calls this:

```
num_to_string(s, num);
```

The code that defines `num_to_string` is defined further up during precompilation:

```
BID_EXTERN_C void bid128_to_string (char *str, BID_UINT128 x _EXC_FLAGS_PARAM);
```

Now `_EXC_FLAGS_PARAM` is evaluated depending on build arguments, defined here:

```
#if !DECIMAL_GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_FLAGS
#define _EXC_FLAGS_PARAM , _IDEC_flags *pfpsf
#else
#define _EXC_FLAGS_ARG
#endif
```

That reads: If the exception flags are not set, then `_EXC_FLAGS_PARAM` becomes "`, _IDEC_flags *pfpsf`" or else "" (nada).

The flag is? set but I still get:

```
error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
  num_to_string(s, num);
```

So `_EXC_FLAGS_PARAM` becomes "`, _IDEC_flags *pfpsf`". But `DECIMAL_GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_FLAGS` is set!...

**...or is it not?**

How can I print out what is actually set while it is happening, like:

```
#please_print_this(DECIMAL_GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_FLAGS)
```

Or even better: see the intermediate output, basically what the compiler ultimately gets fed with...

(No C compiler expert but could not find an answer yet).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gcc, compile with the `-E` option.  That will run *just* the preprocessor and output the result to stdout.  Then you can see what the macros expand to.

Comment: Thank you dbush. That is what I need. Trying to get make to pass that in as run arg. Currently got: `make CC=gcc CALL_BY_REF=1 GLOBAL_RND=1 GLOBAL_FLAGS=1 UNCHANGED_BINARY_FLAGS=1`. Tried `make CC="gcc -E" ...`, no luck yet but getting there.

Comment: @raoulsson Don't worry about `make`, since you can't really use the result.  Just run the gcc command manually and see what you get.

Comment: @raoulsson You'll want to run the `make` command with verbose output e.g. by using `cmake --build ... --verbose`. This should print the command used for compilation of the source file to the console allowing you to add the `-E` option leaving everything else untouched.